# Is there a way to state the dependencies of an R package on github like 'requeriments.txt' from python?

Tags: r, github, dependencies, r-package

Github has a "Dependency Graph" that is accessible from https://github.com/youruser/yourrepo/network/dependencies

Composer, RubyGems, Python PIP, Yarn, npm, Maven, all have a file that describes the package dependencies and these files are automatically read by Github and populates the "Dependency Graph".

I know that R Packages uses the DESCRIPTION file for that. But, there is any known way to tell GitHub about the dependencies?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet: the full list of [Supported package ecosystems](https://help.github.com/en/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/listing-the-packages-that-a-repository-depends-on) does not include R for now (Q1 2020)

> The dependency graph is available for every public repository that define dependencies in a supported package ecosystem using a supported file format.